# How to force simplify to drop common denominator in inequalities?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

`Simplify[c>0 && a/c <= b/c]` results in `c > 0 && a <= b`, as hoped. However when `a` and `b` are even slightly complicated expressions, rather than variables, then even if `c` is still a variable, then `Simplify` no longer drops `c`. Is there a way to force this simplification to be performed?

Comment: Can you also give a (simple) example of a case where your desired simplification does *not* happen? The behavior may depend on the structure of the expression you are simplifying.

Comment: As an example, `c>0 && a/c <= (Sqrt[e^2])/c` is simplified to `c > 0 && (a - Sqrt[e^2])/c <= 0`, while `c>0 && (a*d)/c <= (b*Sqrt[e^2])/c` is not simplified at all.

Answer (score 1):

With version 11.3 use [`MultiplySides`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiplySides.html)

```
ineq = a/c <= b/c;
```

If you know that the denominator is positive,

```
ineq2 = Assuming[c > 0, MultiplySides[ineq, c]]

(* a <= b *)
```

Or, if you know the denominator is negative,

```
ineq3 = Assuming[c < 0, MultiplySides[ineq, c]]

(* b <= a *)
```

**EDIT:** Also, look at [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

```
Reduce[c > 0 && a/c <= b/c]

(* b ∈ Reals && a <= b && c > 0 *)

Assuming[c > 0 && Element[b, Reals], 
  Reduce[c > 0 && a/c <= b/c] // Simplify]

(* a <= b *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, what I am trying to do is not just to simplify a single inequality, but rather simplify a complex boolean combination of a bunch of inequalities...

Comment: That said, `Simplify[MultiplySides[c>0 && (a*d)/c <= (b*Sqrt[e^2])/c, c]` does produce `c > 0 && b*Sqrt[e^2] >= a*d`, so it might be workable - I will try it in my actual example.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the `c>0` part as an *assumption* to the `Simplify` function. Try e.g.

```
Simplify[(a*d)/c <= (b*Sqrt[e^2])/c, c > 0]
Assuming[c > 0, Simplify[(a*d)/c <= (b*Sqrt[e^2])/c]]`

(* Out: a*d <= b*Sqrt[e^2] *)
```

Both remove `c` from the denominator.

Comment: This works with slightly more complex inequalities, but not by far. Also, it does not help simplify more Boolean combinations of inequality, where c>0 is part of a local clause, but is not true for other clauses...